# MySQL Variable as Wildcard String

Tags: mysql, variables, wildcard

The hard coded wildcard keyword return expected result

```
select * from answer a where a.answer like "%grow%";
```

but stops working as soon as I replace the keyword with a variable

```
set @search = "grow";
select * from  answer a where a.answer like concat('"%', @search, '%"');
```

Comment: `'"%'` should just be `'%'`. You're matching a literal `"` at the beginning. And the same for `'%"'`

Comment: If you just want to see it it contains the search string, use the instr function.  Only use like if you actually want % and _ wildcards in your search

Answer (score 0):

Working code based on above @Barmar comment

```
set @search = "grow";
select * from  answer a where a.answer like concat('%', @search, '%');
```